# why does it print length of the list 1 when there are 3 elements in my list

Tags: python

```py
n=int(input()) 
arr=[input().split(",")] 
e=len(arr) 
print(e)
```

the input I gave is n=3 and arr=1,0,2 and its output is 1
why does it print the length of list as 1 instead 3 since it has 3 elements.
if it is wrong way to use what should I use in its place

Comment: `arr=input().split(",")]`, `.split()` already resturns `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping `[input().split(",")]` in a list, so there is only one element (arr will be a list containing a single list).

Use instead: `arr=input().split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

`input().split(",")` statement returns a list. By using `[input().split(",")]`  you are adding retuned list into another list making it a 2D list. According to your code `arr = [[1,0,2]]`. You are getting the length of this 2D list which is 1.